# how can I spawn a house with a command?

Tags: bukkit

Im trying to make a plugin that can create a lot of house for you and I'm not sure how I could make this... I just want to know if you can spawn some block with a command and how can we spawn them.

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a block at a location, you could use

```
location.getBlock()
```

Then, to get set the type of the block, you could use:

```
location.getBlock().setType(material)
```

So, if you wanted to set the block at `0, 0, 0` in `world` to cobblestone, you could use:

```
Location location = new Location(world, 0, 0, 0);
location.getBlock().setType(Material.COBBLESTONE);
```

If you want to paste large saved structures, you should look into [schematics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24110352/2767207)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: What you are trying to do is very complicated and would take a pretty big effort. In order to spawn a house you need to make some sort of system for reading/writing/building schematics. In theory, a player could type a command to spawn a house and pass a schematic name. Your mod could then load up that schematic and start placing it block by block. Your schematic files could be very simple, using letter to represent blocks.

For example: 
C C C
C A C
C C C

The above schematic could load a 3x3 cobblestone layer with air in the center. use the calling players location as the center and build from there.